# Complex query prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, complextype

Yeah, I just was wondering if it is possible to make complex queries in Prolog.

I have a database of tablets with many attributes.

```
tablet(Id, Name).
tablet_operating_system(Id, Operating_system).
tablet_release_year(Id,Release_Year).
tablet_screen_diagonal(Id, Diagonal).
```

and so on...

Well, I need to create a list that matches different conditions:

1. Select all tablets that have (Operating_system: ios or android) AND (their Release_Year is above 2013).
2. Select all tablets that have (Screen_diagonal is above 15 inches AND Release_Year is above 2013) OR Operating_system is ios.
3. Select all tablets that have (Release_Year is above 2010 AND NOT having Operating_system(windows)) OR (Release_Year is less than 2009 AND Operating_system(windows)).

So, if it possible to create complex queries with different conditions and keywords AND, OR, NOT.

I suppose it can't be made with a single query, but what is for many queries. If we have some predicate that will keep a track of current tablets' list.

For example, `(find(operating_system(ios)); find(operating_system(android))), find(release_year(X), X>2013)` will return a list, or put list into some predicate.

Or something like this:

```
find(operating_system(ios), append).
find(operating_system(android), append).
find(release_year(X), X>2013, intersection).
print(cur_list).
```

I do not need help with realization of predicates functionality, i need to find the best way, how to use, how to store, and how to output data after a complex query. I'm looking forward answering your questions, if something is wrong.

Comment: In your first query, do you really mean manufacturers iOS *and* Android? Or do you mean *or*? The first would lead to the empty set. And, by the way, iOS and Android are not manufacturers, but operating systems. ;)

Comment: @lurker, thnx, my mistake, just have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such queries are easily done in Prolog.

Select all tablets that have (OS: ios OR android, AND their Release_Year is above 2013).

```
setof(N, Id^OS^Y^(  tablet(Id, N),
            (  tablet_operating_system(Id, OS),
               member(OS, [iOS, android]),
               tablet_release_year(Id, Y),
               Y > 2013
            )
         ), Names).
```

Select all tablets that have (screen_diagonal is above 15 inches AND Release_Year is above 2013) OR OS is iOS.

```
setof(N, Id^D^Y^(  tablet(Id, N),
            (  (  tablet_screen_diagonal(Id, D),
                  D > 15,
                  tablet_release_year(Id, Y),
                  Y > 2013
               )
            ;  tablet_operating_system(Id, iOS)
            )
         ), Names).
```

Select all tablets that have (Release_Year is above 2010 AND NOT having OS(windows)) OR (Release_Year is less than 2009 AND OS(windows)).

```
setof(N, Id^OS^Y^(  tablet(Id, N),
            tablet_operating_system(Id, OS),
            tablet_release_year(Id, Y),
            (  (Y > 2010, OS \= windows)
            ;  (Y < 2009, OS = windows)
            )
         ), Names).
```

These methods output a list of names. How to use, how to store, etc, all depend upon your application. But in Prolog, a common way to display the results would be either as the result of backtracking:

```
:- query(X, a, b, c).
X = w ;
X = t ;
...
```

Using the query method is good if you want to process the results inside of other predicates one at a time through backtracking.

Or, as above, as a sorted, distinct list with `setof`:

```
:- setof(X, query(X, a, b, c), Xs).
Xs = [w, t, ...]
```

Then you can manipulate all the results as a list.

You'll need to clarify *store*, but if you want to save these results as some kind of facts to a file, you would *assert* them, and possibly write them out as terms using Prolog's file I/O if you needed to save them between sessions. What those terms look like is totally up to you.

Comment: Just one thing, what does `^` mean in a setof predicate?

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov it's an existential quantifier. The purpose of it is to indicate to `setof` that you aren't specifically interested in delineating your results based upon the different instantiations of all the other variables that get you there. You only care about collecting the variable `N`.